# Accessing Pointers and Structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

My issue is to access a variable *'instruct[0]'* of *'ready[1]'* for example, with structs:

```
typedef struct type_program{
     int cont;
     int variable;
     char instruct[30][10];
} type_program;

typedef struct type_tab{
    type_program *executing;
    type_program *ready[10];
    type_program *blocked[10];
} type_tab;
```

thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to use the `.`, `->`, and `*` operators? Assuming you tried some things that didn't work, please edit your post and show some of those attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have created a `type_tab` like so:

```
type_tab some_tab;
```

You can easily access `ready[1]` and `instruct[0]` with:

```
some_tab.ready[1]->instruct[0]
```

However note that `ready` being an array of pointers, forces you to initialize them with `malloc` before using them.

If you have a `type_tab` pointer, because you allocated it in the heap:

```
type_tab *some_tab = malloc(sizeof(type_tab));
```

Then the access will have to be done with:

```
some_tab->ready[1]->instruct[0]
```